# If $(a,b)=1$ and $n$ is a prime, prove that $ (a^n+b^n) /(a+b)$ and $(a+b)$ have no common factor, unless $a+b$ is a multiple of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

How do I solve this without using congruence modulo or Fermat's theorems.
This problem is from a book called challenges and thrills of pre college mathematics, since this problems is from first chapter of the book Fermat's theorem and congruence modulo isn't mentioned so I want to know if there is any other way of solving this problem. I know this problem is repeated but there wasn't a solution without Fermat's theorem or congruence modulo.

My approach was to solve for even primes and odd primes separately. I wasn't able to solve for even primes since $a^n+b^n$ is no

Comment: I wasn't able to ask doubts to the person who first asked this question because my reputation is 3

Comment: I think you mean $a^n + b^n$ instead of the fraction in your title.

Comment: its not fraction actually its ${a^n + b^n}$/(a+b) i cross checked it

Comment: 1/ Can you add in your approach for when $ n = 2$? 2/ Can you do $n = 3$? Where does $\gcd(a+b, n) $ come in? How can it be extended to prime $n$?

Comment: @CalvinLin so we cannot facotrize $a^n+b^n$ when n is even, therefore ($a^n+b^n$/$(a+b)$,$(a+b)$) = 1 and when n is odd prime we can write $a^n+b^n = a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2-...+b^{n-1}$ . Therefore $a^n+b^n$/$(a+b)$ = $a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2-...+b^{n-1}$ but I am not able to do anything after this how should I prove that ($a^n+b^n$/$(a+b)$,$(a+b)$) > 1 iff $(a+b)$ is multiple of n

Comment: A/ Please edit that into the question directly, B/ Just because we cannot factorize doesn't mean that it couldn't work for specific $a, b$. For example, $ \gcd ( a^2 + 2b^2 ) / (a+b) , a+b ) = 3 $ for $ a = 1, b = 2$.  C/ To continue for $n$ odd, show that it is equal to $ \gcd (n b^b, a+b )$.

Comment: You could use [LTE](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/), but I doubt the book intended it to be used.

Comment: Hint; find the remainder when you divide $a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+\dotsb+b^{n-1}$ by $a+b$.

Answer (score 2):

Over here I converted my proof which used congruency to divisibility as they are interchangeable to a large extent.

$$a^n+b^n = (a+b)(a^{n-1}-ba^{n-2}+\cdots+b^{n-1}) \implies \frac{a^n+b^n}{a+b} = (a^{n-1}-ba^{n-2}+\cdots+b^{n-1})$$

Let $x$ be the common factor,

Then,
$$x|(a^{n-1}-ba^{n-2}+\cdots+b^{n-1}) \rightarrow x|(a^{n-1}-ba^{n-2}+\cdots+b^{n-1} - a^{n-1}+a^{n-1})$$
$$\implies x|(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}(a+b)+\cdots+b^{n-1}+a^{n-1})$$
As $x|a+b,$ we can remove $-a^{n-2}(a+b)$.
$$x|(a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}+a^{n-3}b^2-\cdots+b^{n-1}+a^{n-1}-a^{n-1})$$
$$x|(a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}+a^{n-3}(b^2-a^2)-\cdots+b^{n-1}+a^{n-1})$$
As $x|(b+a)(b-a)$, we can remove $a^{n-3}(b^2-a^2)$.

$$x|(a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}+a^{n-1}-a^{n-4}b^3+\cdots+b^{n-1})$$

We can repeat adding $a^{n-1} $and subtracting it, as $x|a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}$  and $x|a^{2k}+b^{2k}$ due to $a+b$ being in their factorization.

At the end we get,$$x|n(a^n-1)$$

As $x|a^{n-1}-b^{n-1}$, if $x|a^n-1$ then it will have to divide $b^n-1$ also which can not happen.

Therefore, $x|n \implies x \in \{1, n\}$. If $x = n$, we must say $$n|a+b \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: Thanks I was able to understand because of you. I could never have come up with this solution i was trying for past 4 days.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$a^7+b^7= (a+b)^2[(a^5+b^5)-2ab(a^3+b^3)+3a^2b^2(a+b)]-7a^3b^3(a+b),$$ but $(a, b)=1$, so $(a+b)$ can have no prime factor in common with $a$ or $b$, so must be a multiple of 7. This generalises: (a+b)^2 is a factor of $a^{4r\pm1}+b^{4r\pm1} \mp(4r\pm1)(a+b)a^{2r}b^{2r}$.